# How to change system language in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, language

I have

```
└─$ locale -a                                                                                                                                            1 ⨯
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

But the system language in console is still Russian and all console programs have output in Russian. Could you tell me how to switch to English completely?
My environment is:

```
└─$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2021.2"
VERSION_ID="2021.2"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"

└─$ uname -r
5.10.0-kali9-amd64
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved by deleting second language (Russian) in KDE regional settings.